# get number of students enrolled in the same course as a specific student

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have two sql queries

```
select course from enrolments where student = 101;

select count(student) as course from enrolments 
GROUP by course
```

The first produces a list of course where student with id 101 is enrolled
The second return a total count of students enrolled in each course

How do I get the total enrolments for the courses student 101 is enrolled in?

Comment: Do you mean total number of enrolments?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result! (All as well formatted text.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff that would return `1` every time (OFC with the grouping OP requested).

Comment: Do you want one number or one number per course.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) in `having` to ensure at least one of the students is `101` in the group:

```
select   count(student) as course
from     enrolments
group by course
having   bool_or(student = 101)
```

For a less PostgreSQL-specific solution, you would need to use a `JOIN` (or `EXISTS`). Something like this:

```
select   count(student) as course
from     enrolments e
where    exists(select 1
                from   enrolments s
                where  s.course = e.course
                and    s.student = 101)
group by course
```

Answer (score 0):

I originally misunderstood the question.  Here is an approach that uses two levels of aggregation:

```
select sum(numstudents)
from (select course, count(*) as numstudents
      from enrolments 
      group by course
      having sum( (student = 1)::int) > 0
     ) c;
```

The subquery gets the value per course.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have to add 'where' condition to your second query:

```
SELECT 
    count(student) as course 
FROM
    enrolments 
WHERE 
    student = 101
GROUP by course;
```